On element's hardcoded children replacement
I'm doing a little website project with a select in which i hardcoded a first non selectable option as placeholder. The point is that afterwards when i dynamically add options they seem to overwrite the hardcoded one.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <select id='select' name='select' required>
        <option hidden disabled selected>Select placeholder</option> 
    </select><br>

<!-- More coding... -->

    <script>
        let a;
        let aSelect = document.querySelector('#select');
        
        fetch('./php/a.php', {
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            a = data;
            a.forEach(at => {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                let axy = at.x + ' ' + at.y;
                option.value = at.id;
                option.text = axy;
                aSelect.appendChild(option);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The above snippet would not show any "Select placeholder" option in the select. But i found that the following, in which i dynamically generate the placeholder option too would.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <select id='select' name='select' required>
    </select><br>

<!-- More coding... -->

    <script>
        let a;
        let aSelect = document.querySelector('#select');
        
        fetch('./php/a.php', {
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            a = data;
            let option = document.createElement('option');
            option.hidden = true;
            option.disabled = true;
            option.selected = true;
            option.text = "Select placeholder";
            aSelect.appendChild(option);
            a.forEach(at => {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                let axy = at.x + ' ' + at.y;
                option.value = at.id;
                option.text = axy;
                aSelect.appendChild(option);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Why's that? I read from the documentation that appendChild should not replace elements but append them after the last one. I thought that maybe hardcoded select options are not considered "elements" so that they are replaced by dynamically generated ones... But it seems unlikely and i can't find anything on the web.
P.S.: don't mind variables names; they're not self-explanatory because they were in my native language but i don't want to translate them.

"The above snippet would not show any "Select placeholder" option in the select." - probably due to the hidden attribute you put on the option, what is that doing there?

no option elements are removed.. it's still there after the json gets processed to add new options to the select. But as said above, the option you chose as placeholder has the hidden attribute so you will see it only at the very beginning when it's still selected. As you change the selected option it will be gone but still there in the dom

your "Select placeholder" option has the hidden state which prevent it from showing. Depending on the browser and its version this triggers different behaviors.
Even when you see the option itself, as soon as u click on it, the option then will hide. It looks like the dynamic access to this selection will trigger this hidden state also which will "remove" it from your view.
So remove the hidden from the option will do the trick:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <select id='select' name='select' required>
        <option disabled selected>Select placeholder</option>
    </select><br>

<!-- More coding... -->

    <script>
        const dummyData = [
            { id: 1, x: "Option 1", y: "Description 1" },
            { id: 2, x: "Option 2", y: "Description 2" },
            { id: 3, x: "Option 3", y: "Description 3" }
        ];

        let a;
        let aSelect = document.querySelector('#select');
        
        Promise.resolve(dummyData)
        .then(data => {
            a = data;
            a.forEach(at => {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                let axy = at.x + ' ' + at.y;
                option.value = at.id;
                option.text = axy;
                aSelect.appendChild(option);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Oh i got it now, thanks. But how can i get the behaviour of showing "Select placeholder" only at first and then make it disappear when selected, evene from the dropdown list?

then make it disappear - select change event, remove the placeholder
